# How to send multiple NFC ISO7816 APDUs in Swift (iOS)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, apdu

I need to send multiple (lets say 50) adpu messages to my iso 7816 nfc tag.

The order needs to be: sending -> receiving response -> do some calculations -> sending -> receiving response -> do some calculations -> sending -> ...

How can I do it?

This code prints "2" before "1" so there is no place to implement response1-dependent calculations:

```
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        session.connect(to: tag) { (error1: Error?) in
        if nil != error1{
         session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection Failed")
        }
        if case let .iso7816(sTag) = tag{
            sTag.sendCommand(apdu: apdu1) { (data:Data, int1:UInt8, int2:UInt8, error:Error?) in
                if error != nil{
                    return
                }
                print("1")
            }
            print("2")
            sTag.sendCommand(apdu: apdu2) { (data:Data, int1:UInt8, int2:UInt8, error:Error?) in
                if error != nil{
                    return
                }
                // ...
```

This code **works**, but creates blocks in blocks. So there can probably happen stack oveflow and *blocks in blocks* are probably not ok with coding conventions etc:

```
    func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
        session.connect(to: tag) { (error1: Error?) in
        if nil != error1{
         session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection Failed")
        }
        if case let .iso7816(sTag) = tag{
            sTag.sendCommand(apdu: apdu1) { (data:Data, int1:UInt8, int2:UInt8, error:Error?) in
                if error != nil{
                    return
                }
                //create apdu2 depend on response1
                sTag.sendCommand(apdu: apdu2) { (data:Data, int1:UInt8, int2:UInt8, error:Error?) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    //create apdu3 depend on response1 and response2
                    sTag.sendCommand(apdu: apdu3) { (data:Data, int1:UInt8, int2:UInt8, error:Error?) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }
                        // ...
```

Are there better alternatives or is this the only functionable solution?

Comment: Rather than writing simple linear code, I suggest you look at using an array of data or perhaps a state machine so that you can have single function that sends the various commands in the right order

Comment: Yea, thanks. One single function can be helpful but if it will send the commands, than this function needs to be recursive (in the case of second code lines). And this will complicate the management of responses etc. And still doesn't solves the stack overflow problem.

Comment: I doubt you would get a stack overflow with a depth of 50, but it doesn't need to be recursive. You can use an operation queue, for example.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't needs to be recursive. The bigger problem is that I don't have a solution for my scenario that will **not** start the next command send from the code block of previous command send. Is there something to launch a event-depend code (analyse previous and send new command) from the main thread that will run after the event happens (response of previous command received)? Now maybe the overflow will not happen, but the code looks bad and stack will be big (is a big function call stack not a problem in general?).

Comment: You certainly want to dispatch the next command from the result of the previous command. As I suggested, submitting the next unit of work to an `OperationQueue` is one way. You could also just use `dispatchQueue.async()`.  A nested "pyramid of doom" of response handlers looks bad.  A deep call stack is generally not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with semaphores, but there are more possibilities as @Paulw11 mentioned in comments

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
    session.connect(to: tag) { (error1: Error?) in
    if nil != error1{
     session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Connection Failed")
    }
    if case let .iso7816(sTag) = tag{
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { //because semaphore.wait() shouldn't block main thread
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
            let apdu1 = //...
            sendApdu(apdu: apdu1, semaphore: semaphore)
            semaphore.wait()
            sendApdu(apdu: apdu2, semaphore: semaphore)
            semaphore.wait()
            sendApdu(apdu: apdu3, semaphore: semaphore)
            semaphore.wait()
        }
    }
}

func sendApdu(apdu: NFCISO7816APDU, semaphore: DispatchSemaphore){
    sTag.sendCommand(apdu: apdu3) { (data:Data, int1:UInt8, int2:UInt8, error:Error?) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        //... analyse response, put next apdu to a class variable etc
        semaphore.signal()
    }
}
```